# Using displace modifier to model a circuit board

Tags: modifiers, displacement

Is it possible to model something as complex as a circuit board using the displace modifier?  I've been working with the settings but can't get it right.  I've UV mapped the image over my mesh and used several subdivisions.  If anyone could show me step by step or point me to a tutorial, that would be awesome.

Here's the image I am trying to model:

[image]

Comment: what do you wish to model: just the board or electronic component also? displace can just create different heights  on a surface... like mountains, or grooves... how can displace be applied here?

Comment: everything....the grooves, chips, holes

Comment: You'll need to provide modifier with accurate displace map where every detail has its own color - chip tp have almost white for extrusion, its details a bit less white to make them extruded less, grooves almost dark to make them intruded.. to make such a color map essentially. And with that even done you won't really get high precision - displace only pushes polygons up and down. It doesn't care about the topology which might become a mess in that case. And amount of subdivisions should be pretty high. So this method seems comfortable but maybe isn't.

Comment: **Short answer**: You totally can. **Long Answer**: You can but it would be a waste of resources. You will need both an incredibly subdivided mesh for this to look  anywhere near presentable, and you will need a large image texture to hold enough detail for all the components to appear well defined. Both of which could be a lot better employed and obtain a better result more efficiently and with a lot less resources with a proper modelling technique.

Comment: Difficulties using displacement: obtaining the good colors from the original image, bridges (how to make transistors or other similar parts), a lot of subdivisions needed, hard to tune the heights, IMO and as said by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, modeling will be better, faster and more accurate

Comment: also holes, resistors, capacitors...I think those are impossible...

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone...I think I should have clarified that super detail isn't important but I do want it to look convincingly 3 dimensional...would bump help to create that effect? Also, if I did want to go the modeling direction, would extruding the chips and resistors be enough with a texture node to do the rest?  It seems like musgrave is doing a good job on the fine grooves so far.